# Reducing size of taskbar context menu in Win10

Tags: windows-10, gui

The taskbar context menus are huge on my monitors, taking more than half of the display height. Very inconvenient.

Is there any way to reduce context menu in size, especially the spacings between the lines (remain the text of the same size)? And how to do that?

[image]

I haven't found anything that could affect taskbar context menus in WindowMetrics in registry.